# sleep() never terminates on Linux

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel, c

I wrote a piece of code in C, using `sleep(0.01);`.
For some reason the machine froze, and according to the backtrace it seems that it hangs on `nanosleep()` or `__kernel_vsyscall ()`.

`(gdb) bt`

`#0  0xffffe430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()`

`#1  0xf6f6bbe6 in nanosleep () from /lib/libc.so.6`

`#2  0xf6f6b9d9 in sleep () from /lib/libc.so.6`

It doesn't happen every time, so it might be a race condition that I fail to understand.

Working on Linux kernel 3.10.

Any idea what might be the cause?

Thanks.

Comment: What architecture are you running (i686)? Which libc version are you running? Can you grep your kernel configuration (/proc/config.gz) for "VSYSCALL"? Can you test the kernel option `vsyscall=emulate`?

Comment: Running on a virtual machine. libc's version is 2.17. Grepping /proc/config.gz: CONFIG_GENERIC_TIME_VSYSCALL=y.
How do I run the kernel option test?

Comment: Virtual machines are still machines with CPUs and they emulate a specific architecture (but I'm guessing it's just standard x86/i686 in this case). Specify the option in the kernel command line, in your bootloader (grub).

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea what might be the cause?

Your argument of `0.01` does not match the type of parameter that is expected/required.
Per the man page for [sleep()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html), the function prototype is:

```
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
```

Instead of an unsigned integer value, you are passing a floating point value, which is being interpreted as a very large integer value.
The sleep timer seems to never expire simply because you have not waited long enough.

There are compiler options that can/should be enabled to error on or at least warn of questionable code (e.g. -Wall).

> It doesn't happen every time, ...

Possibly because the **sleep()** call can be interrupted by a signal handler.  Testing the return code could confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions.

Eventually, I noticed the [man page of nanosleep()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) (which is used by `sleep()`), notifies about a possible problem when using it in a program that receives signals at a very high rate, which might be my case:

> If a program that catches signals and uses nanosleep() receives
>          signals at a very high rate, then scheduling delays and rounding
>          errors in the kernel's calculation of the sleep interval and the
>          returned remain value mean that the remain value may steadily
>          increase on successive restarts of the nanosleep() call.  To avoid
>          such problems, use clock_nanosleep(2) with the TIMER_ABSTIME flag to
>          sleep to an absolute deadline.

I think I'm gonna try this out, as the approach of sleeping until an absolute time rather than sleeping for a relative time, seems better to me.